# how do we embed VF page in a lightning UI

Tags: lightning-experience

We have multiple VF pages embeded in our page layout currently. How does one embed VF page in a Lightning UI? 
Is that even possible in Lightning UI? I am pretty sure this is a common use case in most organizations i would be interested in how everyone is handling this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That feature in BETA right now as per the Saleforce winter '16 release notes

[image]

You can check following trailhead document for detail [Using Visualforce in Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_intro)